# Как передать Parcelable с ArrayList из своих объектов

Tags: android, объекты, android-parcelable

У меня есть ArrayList из своего класса. Пытаюсь передать его через Parcelable, но получаю ошибку
Ниже представлена структура класса и сам код. Как можно передать подобный тип данных?

Сам класс

```
class Lists{
        String name_opt;
        byte[] value;
    }

    class ConfigStruct{
        String page;
        String name;
        String type;
        byte[] val_size;
        byte[] max_lenght;
        byte[] min_lenght;
        byte[] value;
        List<Lists> list;
        View view;
    }
```

Попытка передачи

```
public class ConfigStructParcelable implements Parcelable {

    List<Tabs.ConfigStruct> structs;

    public ConfigStructParcelable(ArrayList<Tabs.ConfigStruct> data){
        this.structs = data;
    }
    public ConfigStructParcelable(Parcel in){

        this.structs = in.readArrayList(null);//?
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeList(structs); //?
    }

    public static Creator<ConfigStructParcelable> CREATOR = new Creator<ConfigStructParcelable>() {
        @Override
        public ConfigStructParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ConfigStructParcelable(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ConfigStructParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ConfigStructParcelable[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Я пометил знаками "//?" места, где необходима помощь.
Пост по ссылке не помог.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042272/how-to-properly-implement-parcelable-with-an-arraylistparcelable/7042757

Comment: Вам надо передать class Lists? (он у вас "Data" класс?)

Comment: Необходимо передать класс ConfigStruct, который включает в себя Lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждый из классов, объекты которых вы хотите передавать в Parcel, должны реализовывать интерфейс Parcelable

1) В классе `Lists` реализовать интерфейс `Parcelable` и конструктор `Lists(Parcel in)`

2) В классе `ConfigStruct` реализовать интерфейс `Parcelable` и конструктор `ConfigStruct(Parcel in)`

В этом классе:

- Для записи `List<Lists> list` в `Parcel` в переопределённой функции `writeToParcel(Parcel out)` использовать `out.writeTypedList(list)`
- Для получения `List<Lists> list` из `Parcel` в конструкторе `ConfigStruct(Parcel in)` использовать `in.readTypedList(list, Lists.CREATOR);`